# How to change the MVC project file´s path for a ASP.NET core project using VS Core when implementing Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have found out that I need to use Areas in asp.net core and the files arent recognized after they have changed the location, is there a file or extension that I should change-use in order for VS Code and the project to recognize the new location of the MVC files?

the original file's path would be like
~\ProjectName\ProjectName\Models
~\ProjectName\ProjectName\Controller
~\ProjectName\ProjectName\Views

when using areas should have a route like

~\ProjectName\ProjectName\Areas\Models
...

now I wonder if there was an easy way to change the file's path using vs code?

i tried editing launch.json but it doesnt recognize ViewModels folder

````
 "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Area/Views",
                "/Controllers" : "${workspaceFolder}/Area/Controllers",
                "/Models":"${workspaceFolder}/Area/Models",
                "/ViewModels": "${workspaceFolder}/Area/ViewModels",
                
            }```
````

Comment: Did "/Views" "/Controllers" and  "/Models" work?

Comment: @MichaelWang yes it worked i had to set the namespace on the files that solved the issue when using areas.